# Discrete distributions flipping a fair coin

Tags: probability

Consider flipping a fair coin. Let $Z = 1$ if the coin is heads, and $Z = 3$ if the coin is tails. Let $W = Z^2 + Z$

(a) What is the probability function of $Z$?

(b) What is the probability function of $W$?

Solution:

(a) $P_z(1) = P_z(3) = 1/2$, with $p_z(z) = 0$ otherwise

(b) $P_w(2) = P_w(12) = 1/2$, with $p_w(w) = 0$ otherwise

---

So for (a) it's because both z = 1 and 3 are 1/2. I don't get (b) how did they get that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $Z=1$, then we have $W=1^2+1=2$

If $Z=3$, then we have $W=3^3+3=12$.

The event that $W=2$ is equal to the event that $Z=1$. hence $Pr(Z=1)=Pr(W=2)=\frac12$.